# Can I remove these 2x4s which were part of the fire place framing I think?

Tags: drywall

I have a fireplace in my family room that I want to remove. There was a recessed portion of the wall right beside so by taking the fire place out I want to extend the recessed portion so it looks proportionate on both ends of the wall. I have cut the dry wall out . Please see the pictures. I want to confirm if the studs on the left side and right above the fireplace are ok to be removed and are not load bearing.

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Likely not load bearing, that short of a run can't carry significant weight.

Comment: considering the one on the left is dual 2x4 (which makes it 4x4) it might be load bearing. what is above it

Comment: It looks to me like the fireplace surround is a bump out from the original wall, thus creating a recess on either side. Am I correct in this and are you looking to remove this entire bump out? If so, then it appears that no, this wouldn't be load bearing in any way and you can safely remove it. Maybe [edit] your question to include a (top-down) drawing of the walls in this part of the house (it doesn't have to be to scale, just indicate dimensions and where the external walls are).

Comment: @asinine or the double stud could simply be so the drywall on that side has space to be screwed into.  Given that the there's no real header over the "fireplace" I doubt it's load-bearing.